# A Lebesgue integrable function whose absolute value is not Lebesgue integrable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F,\mu)$ be a measurable space. Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be $\mathcal F$-measurable.

We know that:
$\int_\Omega |f|d\mu<\infty\implies\int_\Omega fd\mu<\infty $.

If $\int_\Omega fd\mu<\infty$, then this means the function is integrable, and both $\int_\Omega f^+d\mu<\infty$ and $\int_\Omega f^-d\mu<\infty$, which implies that $|f|=f^++f^-$ is also integrable.

If the reverse holds, then both conditions are equivalent, then why do we use the absolute value. Why not spare notation?

Comment: Often the Lebesgue integral of $f$ is not even defined unless $f\geq 0$ or $|f|$ is integrable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes the reverse holds as well. This is really a definitional convention. We typically define "$f$ is integrable" to mean that both $\int_\Omega f^+ d\mu$ and $\int_\Omega f^- d\mu$ are finite (since, in the beginning, we define integration only for non-negative functions) then define $$\int_\Omega f d\mu = \int_\Omega f^+ d\mu - \int_\Omega f^- d\mu.$$ However, if both these are finite, one can easily see that $$\int_\Omega \lvert f \rvert d\mu = \int_\Omega f^+ d\mu + \int_\Omega f^- d\mu$$ and so $\int_\Omega \lvert f \rvert d\mu$ is finite as well.

Edit: @Vladamir has a much better answer in the comments. THe order in which we define things matters here. The value $\int_\Omega \lvert f \rvert d\mu$ is always defined (for measureable $f$). The value $\int_\Omega f \, d\mu$ is only defined when the other value is finite. Thus to check $f$ is integrable, we need to check $\int_\Omega \lvert f \rvert d\mu < \infty$ because *a priori*, the value $\int_\Omega f \, d\mu$ is not defined.

Comment: I always see that a condition for integrability is $\int_\Omega |f|d\mu<\infty$. But this is exactly the same as $\int_\Omega fd\mu<\infty$. Then why the extra "$|\cdot|$"?

Comment: @julian.marr What if $f$ is complex valued?  That's where absolute value is truly needed.

Comment: @user46944 Could you elaborate further on this please?

Comment: Well, since $\lvert f \rvert$ is a non-negative function, we can define $ \int_\Omega \rvert f \lvert d \mu$ without ever thinking about $\int_\Omega f \, d\mu$. By contrast, the definition of $\int_\Omega f \, d\mu$ hinges on the definition of integration of non-negative functions, so perhaps we do this because of the order in which we think about such things. 

Alternatively, if we would like to consider "integrable functions" as a linear space, the natural norm on that space is $\int_\Omega \lvert f \rvert d\mu$ so it is a natural condition to check that this value is finite.

Comment: One cannot write $\int f d\mu<\infty$ if $\int f d\mu$ is not defined in the first place. On the other hand, if $f$ is $\mu$-measurable, then the integral $\int|f|d\mu$ is always defined (but can be infinite), and if it is finite, then $f$ is integrable and the integral of $f$ is well defined.

Comment: @julian.marr Sorry for my late reply.  If $f$ is a complex valued function, then we can write $f(x) = u(x) + i v(x)$ for real valued functions $u$ and $v$ ($u$ is called the real part of $f$, and $v$ is called the imaginary part).  We define $\int f \,d\mu = \int u \,d\mu + i \int v \,d\mu$.  When should this be integrable?  The right hand side is a complex number.  We don't have an ordering $<$ on the complex numbers to say that a complex number $a + bi < \infty$.  So when should we say $\int f \,d\mu$ is integrable? Well, we can take the absolute value of a complex number.

Comment: @julian.marr $|a + bi|$ is defined to be $\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$, which is a real number.  So $|f|$ is a real valued function if $f$ is complex valued.  So we can talk about $\int |f| \,d\mu$, and this is a real number now, so we can talk about when it's finite.

Comment: @julian.marr One final note: if $f(x) = u(x) + i v(x)$, you might be tempted to say "well, I want to say $f$ is integrable if $u$ and $v$ are, i.e., if we have $\int |u| \,d\mu < \infty$ and $\int |v| \,d\mu < \infty$."  And I would reply that you have a great idea, and that actually you *could* define $f$ being integrable in this way.  In fact, it's equivalent to $|f|$ being integrable.  I recommend you try to prove that.  Prove that if $f(x) = u(x) + i v(x)$, and if $f$ is integrable in the absolute value sense, then it is integrable in the $u$, $v$ integrability sense.  Then prove the

Comment: @julian.marr ...converse, that if $u$ and $v$ are integrable, then $f$ is integrable in the absolute value sense.